# Script is running in integrated Terminal on VScode and I want it to run in Output

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am pretty new yo VScode and when I run my python script it is auto running in terminal. I wanna run it in the output but idk how to change it.

I tried spliting it but it just runs in terminal on both sides. I saw that I should unclick the "Run in terminal" box in settings but i couldnt find that anywhere.

Comment: are you using code runner?